# Why isn't cron creating a log even though it is enabled?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, log

The emails on my site are not working so I want to take a look at the Cron log to see what the problem is. It is enabled in configuration and there is a string of code in the cron.php file which should create the log but it isn't happening.

Are there any other files relating to cron that need to be adjusted?

Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: check server side cron.php set properly.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the cron.php file and this seems to be fine.

Comment: what is the code that you think should be creating the log?

Comment: @jscar

try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');

$log = fopen(__FILE__.'.log', 'a');
fwrite($log, date("Y-m-d H:i:s").PHP_EOL);
fclose($log);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}

Comment: and cron.php is not modified at all?

Comment: I believe that it isn't so I am not sure what else is stopping the log from being created. - @jscar

Comment: Hhmmm... just found out that I don't have a cron.log either so now I'm investigating too!

Comment: If you find out why let me know! @jscar